# Method not working on all elements of array

Tags: java, arrays

UPDATED

I need guidance. The goal is to display the conversion of temperature. Input is at the command line consisting of a character, either f (for fahrenheit) or c, followed by a series of integers, (e.g. f 100 250 98), which are then stored in an array of ints.

The output shall be "integers converted to celsius x y z". What I have below does not convert the integers (located at command line args[1], args[2],...) correctly. I ran entered command line argument "f 1500" and the results displayed was "1 integer converted to celsius: -17.2". -17 celsius is 0 fahrenheit, which is obviously incorrect.

I'd like guidance on what I am doing wrong. I do not need the actual lines of code as answers per se just something to steer me in the right direction.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cel2Far
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] temperature = new int[args.length];

        callAndDisplay(args,temperature);
    } // main


    private static void callAndDisplay(String[] args, int[] temperature)
    {
        getTemps(args,temperature);

        switch(args[0]) {
          case "f":
              System.out.printf("%,d %s converted to Celsius: ",
              (temperature.length-1),(temperature.length-1) > 1 ?    
              "temperatures" : "temperature");

              for (int i = 1; i < temperature.length; i++) {                                                                 
                  System.out.printf("%,.1f ", celsius(temperature[i]) );
              }
              break;

           case "c":
               System.out.printf("%,d %s converted to Fahrenheit: ",
               (temperature.length-1),(temperature.length-1) > 1 ?    
               "temperatures" : "temperature");

               for (int i = 1; i < temperature.length; i++) {
                   System.out.printf("%,.1f ", fahrenheit(temperature[i]) );
               }
               break;

         }
         System.out.println();
    }

    private static boolean getTemps(String[] args, int[] temperature)
    {
        boolean message = false;

        if (! (args[0].equals("c") || args[0].equals("f")) ) {
            message =  false;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                temperature[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                message = true;
            }
        }

        return message;
    }

    private static double celsius(int f)
    {

        double c = 5.0 / 9.0 * (f - 32.0);

        return c;
    }

    private static double fahrenheit(int c)
    {
        double f = 9.0/5.0 * c + 32.0;
        return f;
    }
} // class
```

Comment: You're calling your conversion functions with `i`. Surely this should be `temperature[i]`?

Comment: args[0].equals("c") && args[0].equals("f"): that will **always** be false. Nothing can't be equal to "c" and to "f". And you're ignoring the boolean returned by this method, thus hiding the bug.

Comment: I think a problem is `args[0].equals("c") && args[0].equals("f")`. A string will never be equal to c AND to f, you should change it to OR. And you do not evaluate your return of `getTemps` so you do not know if you parsed your values. After fixing it, you will get a problem to parse the first input ("c" or "f") to an integer. You should start at index 1.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the logical errors. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to overcomplicate things. Given on your current example with 2 inputs (first for the format `c` / `f` and the second the actual value)  you can just use the following functions:

```
private static double convert(String format, double temperature){
    switch(format){
        case "f":
            return toCelsius(temperature);

        case "c":
            return toFahrenheit(temperature);
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

private static double toCelsius(double f){
    return 5. / 9. * (f - 32.);
}

private static double toFahrenheit(double c){
    return 9./5. * c + 32.;
}
```

And call it then easily from your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(convert(args[0], Double.parseDouble(args[1]));
}
```

This can also be easily widened if you want to support multiple inputs at once. Either with 1 format and multiple temperatures (`f 20 53 63 74`):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String format = args[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i++){
        System.out.println(convert(args[0], Double.parseDouble(args[i]));
    }
}
```

Or with alternating conversions (`c 56 f 734 f 547 c 598`):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        System.out.println(convert(args[i], Double.parseDouble(args[i+1]));
    }
}
```

Of course in all of these solutions you'd have to ensure that input arguments are given into the programm. E.g. by checking the length of the `args` array.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help. But this online java tutorial I am following begs for 2 methods of converting celsius to fahrenheit and vice-versa.

Comment: The `switch` statement is basically an if and an else-if, does that count?

Comment: @mchlvncntry See the update, does this now work for you? I've just added 2 conversion functions

Comment: "I do not need the actual lines of code as answers" ;)

Comment: @am9417 it is more difficult to write a text explaining everything, than just using code snippets to underline what you mean ;)

Comment: Sure. But I just find it better to underline the existing errors that the OP might not hav efound and how to fix them instead of rewriting the answer which would wipe off the errors. Though rewriting the program is here definitely more reasonable a choice because the initial solution is way overcomplicated.

Comment: @am9417 well there already exist two answer that spoke about the issues. Adding a third would just not make sense

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be several logical mistakes in your code:

In your `switch` statement, you are not calling the `celsius()` or `fahrenheit()` methods with the numbers passed as arguments, but loop indices (`celsius(i)`).

You are always converting 1, 2, 3... celsius to fahrenheit or vice-versa. Use the inputs parsed by `getTemps` in the array `temperature[]` and then pass the correct item from that array to the converting `celsius()` or `fahrenheit()` method.

Also the conditions in your `getTemps` method are wrong. You probably meant to use a `||` operator instead of `&&`, because - of course - a string cannot equal to "c" and "f" simultaneously.

Furthermore, index in the loop that parses Integers should not start from `0` but `1` since the first item is a string "c" or "f" and not an `int`! If you try to parse a non-integer string to an integer, you will probably get a `NumberFormatException` and your program will exit.

Comment: Don't pass the whole array, but a specific item in that array, i.e. `temperature[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem: `if (! (args[0].equals("c") && args[0].equals("f")) )`

The condition can never be true, because the letter can never be both "c" and "f". There should be `||` instead of `&&`.

Because of this problem, the code always goes into the `if` block and never puts the integers into the array `temperature`. Java always initializes numeric variables to `0` by default, so whatever number you enter, the program always converts 0 F to C or vice versa.

Comment: Thnak you! I did change it and it still is giving me headaches.

Comment: Yeah, because of this farhenheit and celsius method is getting 0 as the parameter value.

Comment: @mchlvncntry What kind of "headaches"?

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that the args[0] in this case is still a String... I just need to figure out which for loop I need to edit.